# return string from public static double name()

Tags: c#

i have richTextBox1 that get result from  pingcheck(string,int)  and it works fine 
but there is one thing i want add it its when toaltime=0 it show "the connection is not available" in richTextBox1
and this is my code

```
public static double pingcheck(string host, int echonum) // i tried to change to (string host ,int echonum,string result) and add this string if total time =0 but its not retrieve it i tried to create public string but couldn't take string
    {
        long totaltime = 0;
        int timeout = 120;
     Ping pingsender = new Ping();//send ping

        for (int i = 0; i < echonum; i++)
        {
            PingReply replay = pingsender.Send(host, timeout);
            if (replay.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
            totaltime += replay.RoundtripTime;
            }
            else if(totaltime==0)
            {
         string getipstatue = "the connectin is not available ";//i want show this text in richTextBox if total time is=0
            }


        }
        return totaltime / echonum;        
    }
private void buttonX1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
richTextBox1.Text += (pingcheck("8.8.8.",1))+Environment.NewLine; //this will show replay  
richTextBox2.Text += (pingcheck("8.8.1.",1))+Environment.NewLine;//i want this one get"the connection is not available pleas check" 
}
```

im using windows form application

Comment: In you case, I suggest returning `Double.NaN` and test for `NaN` when creating the message

Comment: i have already low reputation :) please its been 2 days i have worked on this and i didn't put the effort it was so mess can any one please make it up....

Comment: Ok, let's do it right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot return `string` from function of type `double`.

### The solution of the problem

What is the problem to check for zero return value?

```
public static double PingCheck(string host, int echonum) 
{
    long totaltime = 0;
    int timeout = 120;
    Ping pingsender = new Ping();

    for (int i = 0; i < echonum; i++)
    {
        PingReply replay = pingsender.Send(host, timeout);
        if (replay.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            totaltime += replay.RoundtripTime;
        } else {
            return 0.0;
        }
    }

    // at least, one of them should be double to avoid integer division
    return (double)totaltime / echonum; 
}

private void buttonX1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pingCheckResult = PingCheck("8.8.8.", 1);

    richTextBox1.Text += pingCheckResult > 0 
        ? pingCheckResult.ToString("F2") + Environment.NewLine 
        : "the connectin is not available";
}
```

### There are many other ways to do this

1. For example, you can use `out` parameters and make a method with the following definition:

   ```
   public static bool PingCheck(string host, int echonum, out double approximateTime) 
   {
       long totaltime = 0;
       int timeout = 120;
       Ping pingsender = new Ping();

       for (int i = 0; i < echonum; i++)
       {
           PingReply replay = pingsender.Send(host, timeout);
           if (replay.Status == IPStatus.Success)
           {
               totaltime += replay.RoundtripTime;
           } 
           else 
           {
               approximateTime = 0.0;
               return false;
           }
       }

       // at least, one of them should be double to avoid integer division
       approximateTime = (double)totaltime / echonum;
       return true;
   }

   private void buttonX1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       double appTime;
       if (PingCheck("8.8.8.", 1, out appTime))
       {
           richTextBox1.Text += appTime.ToString("F2") + Environment.NewLine;
       } else {
           richTextBox1.Text += "the connectin is not available";
       }
   }
   ```
2. Or you can throw an exception in your `PingCheck` and catch it in `buttonX1_Click`.
3. Or you actually can make your method return `string` and do the following:

   ```
   public static string PingCheck(string host, int echonum) 
   {
       long totaltime = 0;
       int timeout = 120;
       Ping pingsender = new Ping();

       for (int i = 0; i < echonum; i++)
       {
           PingReply replay = pingsender.Send(host, timeout);
           if (replay.Status == IPStatus.Success)
           {
               totaltime += replay.RoundtripTime;
           } 
           else 
           {
               return "the connectin is not available";
           }
       }

       return (totaltime / echonum).ToString("F2");        
   }
   ```

   However, for me it seems to be incorrect in terms of OOP. Your method returns formatted number or error message. It is pretty inobvious and inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's do it right. First, any method should do its own work, in your case the work is to compute
the *average time to ping the host*. What's `pingcheck` mean? Let's change the name:

```
  // 120 was a magic number, now it's a parameter
  // do you really want to pass attempts each time you call the method? No
  public static Double PingAverageTime(String host, int attempts = 3, int timeout = 120) {
    // Validate the input
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(host))
      throw new ArgumentNullError("host");
    else if (attempts <= 0)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeError("attempts");
    else if (timeout < 0)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeError("timeout");

    Double totalTime = 0; // Double: we don't want integer divison problems

    using (Ping ping = new Ping()) { // IDisposable - into using!
      PingReply replay = ping.Send(host, timeout);

      if (replay.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        totalTime += replay.RoundtripTime;
      else // not succeeded: so the time is infinite
        return Double.PositiveInfinity; // no connection - average time is infinite
    }

    return totalTime / attempts;
  }
```

then use the method:

```
  Double time = PingAverageTime("8.8.8.", 1);

  richTextBox1.Text += Double.IsInfinity(time) 
    ? "the connectin is not available " 
    : time.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to:

```
public static string pingcheck(string host, int echonum) 
{
    ...

        else if(totaltime==0)
        {
            return "the connectin is not available ";//i want show this text in richTextBox if total time is=0
        }

    ...
    return (totaltime / echonum).ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: That text is already returned from the method @Steve. OP just doesn't return it.

Comment: Hey, why downvoting?!! This is exactly what he needs!!! Of course: he needs to replace "..." with his method body. I thought it was obvious.

Comment: The type casting is done using `"" + `. A bad convention indeed, but it works.

Comment: @vojta I took the liberty to edit your answer to make it work. If you don't mind... If you do, please rollback the eidt.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: I testet it - and yes it works didn´t try THAT beore